# PXE boot ubuntu 12.04 Customization

Tags: server, nfs, pxe

Just configured my Ubuntu 12.04 server to play host to a diskless PXE/NFS system. Currently I'm deploying the Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop Live CD to all my clients (derived from the install CD). My question is, how do i enroll a custom image (i.e. loading custom software, custom backgrounds, configs, drivers, etc) to all the clients?

I used the following [Tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallMultiDistro) to configure my server.

Any suggestions, I'm unable to find any good tutorials for this.

Found these sites but am I on the right path?
[Remastersys](http://lifehacker.com/5645072/make-your-own-customized-ubuntu-live-cd-or-usb-drive) | [UCK](http://www.howtogeek.com/109736/how-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-or-usb/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on diskless cluster too. There is two ways to backup your whole OS system.

```
   1- You can use Remastersys(stopped development) or Relinux(implement of remastersys, still developing) to bakcup then copy it to NFS.
   2- You can copy whole OS system as a backup to NFS.
```

There are some advantages and disadvantages of both. Yout have to make new iso file when you want to update system, change some configurations etc. or you can use [Aufs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufs) if you choose first option. I choose second option. One time I copy whole OS to NFS then I can change any files on it without do some extra works.

For second option, I highly recommended to you [this](http://www.serenux.com/2011/04/howto-create-a-diskless-workstation-that-boots-from-pxe-using-ubuntu/comment-page-2/#comment-72360) site. HyRax explains all steps you have to do.